# Using Mapbox maps with WhirlyGlobe

Tags: ios, mapbox

Is there a way to use Mapbox maps (custom maps made in Mapbox Studio) with the WhirlyGlobe library?

I have, so far been able to create a custom map style, but can't seem to go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ask this on the WG-Maply Issues page?  I don't typically run support through stackoverflow.

Comment: No, I haven't posted on the the WG-Maply Issues page, as I don't think this is an issue, but it's something I've been struggling to implement. But I think I have found a solution.